# How to run commands as admin in Windows

Tags: windows-vista, administrator, cmd.exe

OS: Windows Vista

I would like to press `WIN+R` and run commands I enter there as admin for example:

`mstsc /span -admin` like this. ( i know -admin does nothing )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Elevation Powertoy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/elevationpowertoys/).

Just put the "elevate.cmd" into a folder in your path.  Then elevate commands:

`elevate mstsc /span`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do WIN+R without disabling UAC, which you don't want to do.

Another alternative would be to create a shortcut to cmd.exe within your system folder. Right click the shortcut > Properties > Advanced > Run as Administrator (Tick Box).

Save this to your desktop and run it whenever you wish. I am sure you would reconfigure your Windows shortcuts to run this by default under WIN+R if you so wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's sadly not an option I'm working on customer computers which means I can just do that.

Comment: Well if you're wanting a solution for yourself I would suggest the shortcut as a temporary measure, but if your customer doesn't want to change UAC settings, use a shortcut and/or reassign default shortcut keys there really isn't much you can do about it.

I would also point out if it's a customer machine unless they have a specific reason to need an admin terminal every time they open one they should leave the security as it is to avoid system problems.